# Enviar CURL entre dos servidores con ssl auto firmado

Tags: curl, ssl, openssl

Tengo montado en un servidor, un `Sentry` con docker y nginx. He seguido esta [guia](https://blog.neversyn.com/install-sentry-with-docker-easily/)

Bueno pues ahora intento hacer una llamada con curl desde php y comandos. Y no consigo que se pongan de acuerdo los servidores para aceptarse los certificados.

Tengo un certificado en sentry construido:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out MyCertificate.crt -keyout MyKey.key
```

Y luego en el cliente, he echo lo que apareve [aqui](https://leehblue.com/add-self-signed-cert-curl/)

Y nada, he probado anadiendo los certificados:

```
curl_setopt($this->_curl_instance, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '/home/MyKey.key');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLENGINE, 'ssh-rsa'); 
curl_setopt($this->_curl_instance,CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/home/MyCertificate.crt');
```

El error que me da es:

> (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed

Tambien he probado con http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

No se que mas hacer para que acepten los certificados